# SQL combine columns based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I've got a list of items and two locations (X and Y) that these items can be in.these two locations have these items in different quantities.
So When someone places an order for a few items, the items can be pulled from either of these two locations.

Below is the 'Orders' table I've created but it shows two columns for two locations and available stock.

```
ItemNumber          Location    Stock X     Stock Y
A                      X          12          32
B                      X          10          54
C                      X           5          23
A                      Y          54          30
C                      Y          65          36
D                      Y          76          23
E                      X          12          31
F                      X          32          19
F                      Y          72          40
```

What I want to see is available stock for the requested location in a column, not both locations and stock availability in two columns as I've done above.
Result table I Want to see is,

```
ItemNumber          Location    Avail Stock
A                      X          12          
B                      X          10          
C                      X           5          
A                      Y          30
C                      Y          36
D                      Y          23
E                      X          12          
F                      X          32          
F                      Y          40
```

I just cant get my head around this to do it. great if anyone could help or tell me if its even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` expression:

```
SELECT ItemNumber,
       Location, 
       CASE WHEN Location = 'X' THEN [Stock X] 
            WHEN Location = 'Y' THEN [Stock Y] 
       END Avail_Stock 
FROM Orders
```

Comment: HI,  I tried this earlier but it gives me a. "Incorrect Syntax near '=' " error?

Comment: its worked now I had a CASE Location WHEN. thats what gave me the error.

Comment: don't forget to mark it as answer if it is helped. @SanjayaWeerakkody

Answer (score 0):

You have the `union` tag, so:

```
SELECT ItemNumber,
       Location, 
       [Stock X] AS Avail_Stock
  FROM Orders
 WHERE Location = 'X'
UNION
SELECT ItemNumber,
       Location, 
       [Stock Y] AS Avail_Stock
  FROM Orders
 WHERE Location = 'Y'
```